# How to use presentViewController to go to a viewcontroller and perform or invoke a method in it in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a couple of "ViewControllers" and one for Update a picture in an iOS app.
The first one has a button when tapped asks if the user wants to use gallery photo or camera.
Now i am presenting this controller by using `presentViewController` on `self`.

But when the second view controller is presented i want to set the `UIImagePicker` source according to what the user has passed in.

I have made 2 different methods. one with camera source and one with "photoslibrary".
I don't know how to invoke one of these methods based on the use choice from the previous controller.
Am i going the right way with this approach? or should i just have one controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are two ways of passing data to a view controller.

**Storyboard**
If you are working with storyboard segues (that is, control drag from your "root" view controller to the destination view controller, choose a transition style and define a identifier), you can present the view controller
via

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Most of the times your destination view controller will be a custom class, so define a public property to hold the data you want to pass through. Then implement the following in your "root" view controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Setup the location menu delegate
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"]) {
        // The custom class of your destination view controller,
        // don't forget to import the corresponding header
        ViewControllerCustomClass *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        // Set custom property
        vc.chosenImageId = self.chosenImageId;
        // Send message
        [vc message];
   }
}
```

*Hints:*
If your destination view controller is the root view controller of a navigationViewController you can access it via `[[segue.destinationViewController childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];` Additionally, as `sender`is an id, you can "abuse" it to pass any object through, just as a NSDictionary, for example.
Also note, that when I am referring to the root view controller, I am talking of the view controller from which we segue to the destination from.

**Programmatically**

```
ViewControllerCustomClass *vc = [[ViewControllerCustomClass alloc] init];
vc.chosenImageId = self.chosenImageId;

// If you want to push it to the navigation controller
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

// If you want to open it modally
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Cheers for the quick reply. Just one question. In the second line where you've set vc.yourCustomProperty. Is it possible to call a method of that controller(Vc) after its presented. eg:  [vc someMethod];

Comment: Yes, the destination view controller is already initialized at this point and receives messages.

Comment: alright, cheers mate. i ll give it a go and let you know soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inheritance`, make your previous controller superClass, and invoke method in `presentViewController` in `viewDidload`.